# Python regular Expression for windows path

Tags: python, regex

I have

```
d = re.search(r'c:\wng\Qmns\vin2_2012-12-13_RES',r'c:\wng\Qmns\vin2_2012-12-13_RES_1.xls').
```

Its returning None.What am i missing here?It should find the string know?

Comment: If you want to filter a list of files for a pattern, use [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/glob.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:14:39) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r'c:\wng\Qmns\vin2_2012-12-13_RES',r'c:\wng\Qmns\vin2_2012-12-13_RES_1.xls')
>>> re.search(r'c:\\wng\\Qmns\\vin2_2012-12-13_RES',r'c:\wng\Qmns\vin2_2012-12-13_RES_1.xls')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f9c2000bb90>
>>>
```

Comment: I am getting path in a variable say path = 'c:\wng\Qmns\vin2_2012-12-13_RES',how do i change it to 'c:\\wng\\Qmns\\vin2_2012-12-13_RES'

Comment: You have regex pattern in a variable? Why would you need to? Try doing `pattern.replace('\\', r'\\')`. Or if you need to find the path in a text, why not using `str.find`?

Answer (score 0):

You need double escapes on the match side but not on the target:

```
>>> re.search(r'c:\\wng\\Qmns\\vin2_2012-12-13_RES',r'c:\wng\Qmns\vin2_2012-12-13_RES_1.xls')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x105ba34a8>
```

Answer (score 0):

To check whether a string starts with another string, you don't need regexp:

```
path = r'c:\wng\Qmns\vin2_2012-12-13_RES_1.xls'

if path.startswith(r'c:\wng\Qmns\vin2_2012-12-13_RES'):
    ...
```

Comment: Agree.But wat i was acutally trying d = re.search(r'c:\wng\Qmns\vin2_2012-12-13_RES_(\d+)',r'c:\wng\Qmns\vin2_2012-12-13_RES_1.xls'),inorder to extract the last numerical after result